# can't use await on caller and callee?

Tags: .net-core, wampsharp

I'm writing a simplest caller console app according to this [article](https://wampsharp.net/wamp2/roles/caller/getting-started-with-caller/) with core3.1. When i changed `channel.Open().Wait(5000);` to `await channel.Open();`, it's stucked at line `proxy.Ping();`.

And this is also found on a callee:

```
Task openTask = channel.Open();
openTask.Wait();
```

can't replace with `await channel.Open();`

```
Task<IAsyncDisposable> registrationTask = realm.Services.RegisterCallee(instance);
registrationTask.Wait();
```

can't replace with `await realm.Services.RegisterCallee(instance);`

Once await is used, the program always gets stuck at line `proxy.Ping();`

The solution [zipfile](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqxJcIfHZ18Udy4EV7O4OxuJzFs?e=oZ6cKT).

Why?Isn't await waiting?

Comment: "can't replace", why not? If you mix `await` and `.Wait`, most likely one is blocking the other, you're getting deadlocked. Proper use of `.Wait` is difficult to achieve, and it might be that you introducing `await` in one or two places have upset a delicate balance of timing.

Comment: I don't seem to mix  await and wait.Maybe it's not easy for me to understand.

Comment: You will have to provide more code for this question to be answerable. It might be that if it works with `.Wait` but not with `await` it might be that the objects involved might be thread-bound, which means they belong to a certain thread and only work on that thread.

Comment: I've packaged and uploaded the entire solution.[zip](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqxJcIfHZ18Udy4EV7O4OxuJzFs?e=oZ6cKT). Thanks.

Comment: Your ping method is blocking the WebSocket thread. Switch to the `PingAsync` format (recommended approach) or else add an `await Task.Yield()` before the call to Ping in order to release the WebSocket thread (less recommended).

Comment: @dakl I modified it and it still doesn't work.[modified file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqxJcIfHZ18Udy4EV7O4OxuJzFs?e=zvZ7jn)

Comment: Your `Console.Readline()` in the Calle Program.cs blocks the WebSocket thread. Add an `await Task.Yield()` before it.

Comment: @darkl It's done.THS. I can't accept a answer in the comments. Can you formally answer this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method call `proxy.Ping()` blocks the Websocket thread. If you use async syntax, you should be careful not to block the Websocket thread. Use the `await proxy.PingAsync()` version. If you need to make blocking calls like `Console.ReadLine()`, make sure to release the Websocket thread by calling `await Task.Yield()` before making your blocking call.

Comment: Yes, it did. Ths.Maybe it should be hosted in WinForm.